# Whether Django need licence while deployment?

Tags: python, django, deployment, open-source

I have found Django is a open source framework and we can develop a web application using django for free  of cost but what i need to know is whether it is free for commercial deployment with apache server..Or it will ask licence while deployment??

Comment: Totally free, even for commercial deployments. If you want the exact terms, I believe these are the most recent: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/LICENSE

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django is free software. You don't need any special licence for deploying and running a service created with.